# Delimiter deciedes variable and value in php

Tags: php

I am using php. I have a text file which delimits two things like shown below:

Orange;100kg
Apple;400kg
Peach;543 Kg

I want to make orange as variable and assign  100kg as value.

```
$orange="100kg";
$Apple="400kg";
$Peach="543kg";
```

Please I don't want to convert text file into json.

Comment: Do you really need variables with these names? Wouldn't array with keys be okay? Like `$fruits["Apple"] = "100kg"`

Comment: Save the data by serializing a variable or an array: https://www.php.net/serialize THEN when you want to read that data UNserialize it: https://www.php.net/unserialize. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could use some regex to match the variables and values you are looking for and use those to generate PHP vars like so:

```
$fileData = '$orange="100kg";$Apple="400kg";$Peach="543kg";';

$patternVars = '/(?<=\$).*?(?=\=)/m';
$patternValues = '/(?<="(?!;)).*?(?=")/m';

$vars = preg_match_all($patternVars, $fileData, $varMatches); // Match all variables 
$values = preg_match_all($patternValues, $fileData, $valueMatches); // Match all values 

forEach($varMatches[0] as $key => $value){
    // Use the value to name your variable (hence the weird looking "$$") and set the value of this variable to the matches of your values.  
    $$value = $valueMatches[0][$key];
}

var_dump($orange); // Will output "100kg"
```

Or see this [interactive example](https://3v4l.org/joQPR).

If I were you I would look into other options too (if possible). If you file is not formatted everywhere like your example you may get unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are tryna do. Additionally, It's not a good idea to assign a value to a variable whose name we don't know. However, I came up with the code below:

```php
<?php
$text = "Orange;100kg Apple;400kg Peach;543 Kg";
$regex = '/(?<variable>\w+);(?<number>\d+)(\s+)?(k|K)(g|G)/m';
preg_match_all($regex, $text, $matches);
$length = count($matches["variable"]);
for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) { 
    $variableName = $matches["variable"][$i];
    $number = $matches["number"][$i];
    ${$variableName} = $number . "kg";
}
echo $Orange . PHP_EOL;
echo $Apple . PHP_EOL;
echo $Peach . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

### Output

```
100kg
400kg
543kg
```

### Explanation

`${"variableName"}` assigns the value after the equal mark to a variable whose name is `variableName`. So, if you call `echo $variableName` it will show you the value assigned to this variable.